# Does StreamWriter work inconsistently with relative paths?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, file-io, linq-to-xml

I am trying to save a LINQ XML document using a StreamWriter. Using the following code works fine when the document is small (~6kb on disk) but doesn't work when the file is larger (~66kb on disk). If I replace the relative path with an absolute path it works fine in both situations. Is there any reason why the relative path should fail with a larger file?

NB: I am not getting any exception, but no file is created/written to unless I use an absolute path (with the larger dataset - smaller dataset works fine with relative path)

```
XDocument xMap = new XDocument( ... );

// Works for small file but not large
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("map.xml", false, new UTF8Encoding(false))) {
    xMap.Save(writer);
}

// Works consistently
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\data\map.xml", false, new UTF8Encoding(false))) {
    xMap.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: You're probably in the wrong directory; see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason that using a relative path would make it fail for large files.

Are you sure that the relative path ended up being where you think it is?  If the relative path is on a network, or if its drive is full, that could explain it.

What exception are you getting?

---

**EDIT**: The current directory probably changed for some reason.  Check the value of `Environment.CurrentDirectory`when it fails and make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: I'm not getting any exception, it's failing silently. If the data I am saving contains only a small number of elements, it saves and I can see the file appear in the folder. If I then increase the dataset by loading from a larger source, and then click save again, no exception is thrown, but no file appears in the directory.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I thought the CurrentDirectory was supposed to remain as the directory from which the executable runs?

Comment: No; the current directory can change.  For example, the file dialogs can set the current directory.